# Different values when trying to use window in rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I've been having a problem using windows in rasterio, which is probably a misunderstanding on my part.

My goal is to dump a specific data from a band into a csv file, first I tried to use a window but the results differ from the results that I see on QGIS (the results appear to be shifted 1 position).
So I decided to try to read the whole band, instead to use a window, and the result match with QGIS.

I think that I am doing something wrong when I create/use, what I tried to do was:

- create a window from the bounds of the desired area:

  `bandWin = rasterio.windows.from_bounds(*boundingBox,band.transform)`
- get the transform matrix of that window:

  `win_transform = band.window_transform(bandWin)`
- Obtain the window data:

  `win_data = band.read(1, window = bandWin)`
- Get the desired window indexes:

  `indexes = rasterio.transform.rowcol(win_transform, [Xs], [Ys])`
- Get the values that I want:

  `csvData.append(win_data[indexes[0],indexes[1]][0])`

The only differences between when I don't use a window is that instead of using win_transform I use band.transform and read the whole band.